# Why are content and view reported to be deleted from administrator users?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-8, drupal-modules, drupal-views

In the CMS login, it says that administrator users have deleted the content and the view, but the user hasn't deleted them.

Why are content and view reported to be deleted from administrator users?

Comment: You have to provide more information on this.

Comment: My Content has been removed and client say he have not deleted and Log said Deleted by admin @MilanG

Comment: Maybe your client shared admin account credentials with somebody else? Or site was hacked?